# drawing bivariate gaussian distributions in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, matplotlib, normal-distribution

How can we plot (in python matplotlib) bivariate Gaussian Distributions , given their centers and covariance matrices as numpy arrays?

Let's say that our parameters are as follows:

```
center1=np.array([3,3])
center2=np.array([5,5])
cov1=np.array([ [1.,.5], [.5,.1]])
cov2=np.array([ [.2,.5], [.5,.2]])
```

Answer (score 3):

For future reference, there is a `matplotlib.mlab` function called [`bivariate_normal`](http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.bivariate_normal) that should do what you want, a visual example can be seen in the [examples gallery](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_demo.html).